# jquery issue after ajax load

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal-7, view

i jquery applied to a exposed filter to force the look of a drop down with checkboxes which works fine until the ajax reloads the content and cause the slideToggle to open and close immediately. i switched it to just css height and the box wont open after ajax reload. Anyone have any ideas or options that might work after ajax reload. 
 just css option

```
boxes1.css({"display" : "none", "background": "#f2f2f2", "border" : "1px solid #ccc", "padding":"5px", "margin-top" : "25px","position":"absolute","overflow" : "hidden"});
title.live("click",function(){
    if(boxes1.is(":hidden")){       
        boxes1.css({"height" : "300", "display" : "block"});
    } 
    else {
        boxes1.css({"display" : "none"});
    }
});
```

slideToggle option

```
boxes1.css({"display" : "none", "background": "#f2f2f2", "border" : "1px solid #ccc", "padding":"5px", "margin-top" : "25px","position":"absolute","overflow" : "hidden"});
title.live("click",function(){      
    boxes1.slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Would you please clarify your question more?

Comment: @OmarSharif i really dont know how to clarify more. My issue is on ajax reload the jquery doesnt work or function properly. No matter if its a plugin js script or jquery in file once ajax reloads the search all jquery is either tossed or not functioning properly.